# Storyboard and xib in the same project?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, xib

I am working on a project and for some reason there is a main.storyboard and a screen.xib file both in the same objective-c project.  The project is done on Xcode.  To my understanding, it should only be one or the other.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: I use multiple storyboards and xibs all the time. One counterexample disproves the proposition.

Answer (score 1):

An Xcode project can use a combination of .nibs, .xibs, and storyboards.

> iOS uses nibs as an implementation detail that supports storyboards,
>   the iOS user interface design layout format. Storyboards allow you to
>   design and visualize the entire user interface of your app on one
>   canvas. For iOS developers, using storyboards is the recommended way
>   to design user interfaces.

<sub>*the same holds true for OS X as well, although depending on what you're creating storyboards might not be recommend.</sub>

↳ [Cocoa Core Competencies : Nib File](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/NibFile.html)